# How do you write a really simple <li> rotator, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have been scouring through the Internet trying to find a simple `<li>` rotator with the same functionality as that on the Twitter homepage(Top Tweets) before signing in.

I'm going through a JQuery book but the rotator doesn't meet the simplicity of what I need it for...plus I'm a novice.

Does anyone know how to achieve this...Also I have come across the Cycle plug-in for JQuery but I really would like to understand what's going on behind the scenes & expand my knowledge

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having to guess a bit at what you mean by "rotator", but:

```
var counter, list;

// Initial fill
list = $('#thelist');
for (counter = 0; counter < 5; ++counter) {
  $("<li>" + counter + "</li>").appendTo(list);
}

// Start rotating
setInterval(rotate, 1000);

// Rotator function
function rotate() {
  var list = $('#thelist');
  list.find("li:first").remove();
  $("<li>" + counter + "</li>").hide().appendTo(list).fadeIn();
  ++counter;
}
```

([Live example](http://jsbin.com/ogivo3/3)) If you want to grab new `li` data from the server, you'll need to use [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), but other than that the basic idea is the same.

Comment: J.Crowder - basically I'm trying to re-create the Top Tweets widget on the Twitter homepage ( http://twitter.com/ )...it cycles a list...I'm looking to cycle ten `<li>` items...but only have a maximum of 5 showing at any given time. I hope that has cleared it up somewhat, thanks

Comment: @Nasir: Easily done. I've updated the example to only show five rather than 10 items, and to fade in the new ones. I also slowed it down as it was a bit frenetic at the original pace I gave it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

Your list

```
<ul class="fadein">
    <li>element 1</li>
    <li> element 2 </li>
</ul>
```

set the `li to display:none in css`

Write a simple JQuery looping function

```
$(function(){
fade();
});

function fade(){
$("ul.fadein > li:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow", function() {
setTimeout(fade, 1000);
});
```

You can set the fadeIn time to ("fast") or change the setTimeout value > or < 1000 to make it faster.

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/aardvark/XaC3v/) to get you started

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Say I wanted to keep 5 list items always visible...then remove the first list item...then a new list item fades in at the bottom of the list. How would I achieve this effect like the Twitter'top tweets' section on the homepage?